# Extending and defining function signatures in TypeScript

Tags: class, typescript, interface, abstract-class, typescript-typings

Is it possible to assign a function signature to a name?

For example, some external module provides an interface

```
interface ExtFunctionInterface {
    (arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean
}
```

I would like to create a local interface or abstract class that assigns the above interface signature, to a method name. For example:

```
interface MyLocalInterface {
    someMethodName typeof ExtFunctionInterface 
}
```

or

```
abstract class MyLocalAbstractClass {
    public abstract someMethodName typeof|signature of ExtFunctionInterface 
}
```

So that when the interface is implemented or the class is extended:

```
class MyClass {implements|extends} MyLocal{Interface|AbstractClass} {

    // Correct impl
    public someMethodName(arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean {
        // impl
    }

    // Compiler would complain that the function is not implemented
    // correctly because "arg2" is missing or type is wrong for e.g.
    public someMethodName(arg1: string): boolean {
        // impl
    }

}
```

This means that when ExtFunctionInterface is changed, the compiler would notify that the signature is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interfaces, the answer is simpler then you might expect, just declare a field on the interface and you will get the desired behavior:

```
interface MyLocalInterface {
    someMethodName : ExtFunctionInterface 
}

class MyClassFromInterfce implements MyLocalInterface {
    // Will satisfy the interface 
    public someMethodName (arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean {
        return false;
    }
    // Will not satisfy the interface parameter is of the wrong type
    public someMethodName(arg2: number): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For abstract classes you can define an abstract field, unfortunately you can't implement it as a member function, you need to do it as a field containing the function, which should be an ok work around in most cases:

```
abstract class MyLocalClass {
    abstract get someMethodName() : ExtFunctionInterface 
}

class MyClass extends MyLocalClass {
    // Ok 
    public someMethodName  = (arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean => {
        return false;
    }
    // Not ok
    public someMethodName = (arg2: number): boolean => {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note** In the question you want the compiler to warn if there are fewer arguments, this is not the way typescript checks function compatibility (not just in this case, but in general). A function with fewer parameters will be compatible with a signature requiring more. Typescript will warn about argument type mismatch. For example :

```
class Base {
    method(arg1: string, arg2: number) {}
}
class Derived extends Base {
    // We can override with fewer parameters 
    method(arg1: string) {}
    // We can't override if parameter types are missmatched  
    method(arg1: number) {}

    // We can override with more parameres if they are optional  
    method(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3?: number) {}
    // But not if they are required
    method(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks the `get` "workaround" for abstract classes is good. It recognises (TS 2.7.1) it when it's a method and not a property as well... so that's just what I was looking for.